# Website Monitoring Libraries

Tags: monitoring, web, polling

There has been some talk of Website performance monitoring tools and services on stackoverflow, however, they seem fairly expensive for what they actually do.  Are there any good opensource libraries for automating checking/monitoring the availability of a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know if your server is serving out content or not, take a look at [Montastic](http://www.montastic.com/).  I use it, and am pleased.  Plus its free!

It will ping your site periodically, and if it doesn't get a 200 status, it lets you know.

Answer (score 1):

Intelligent website monitoring by simulating a human user is done with Sahi + OMD.
http://www.nagios-wiki.de/_media/workshop/2012/sahi2omd_simon_meggle_monitoring_workshop_2012.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have always used [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) especially for critical web sites.  It uses MySql for the database and it has a PHP frontend.  Of course it is open source and it is very flexible.  It uses servers to stick data in the database and agents collect the data and send it to the servers.  It is very scalable with this respect.  I cannot recommend this software enough.  I have all kinds of monitoring going on, not just web servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out mon.itor.us as well.

Comment: It seems to be a service and the OP wanted a library.